# Looking for 3rd party rich html editor

Tags: richhtmlfield, html-editor

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. On a site collection which publishing infrastructure is enabled. Our users use the OOTB html editor to create web pages (under Pages library and with .aspx extension). However they are not happy with it because the "table-related" function is very limited. They cannot plot the table they want unless they directly edit HTML code.

Is there any good 3rd party solution can help? Thank you for information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really but it depends on for what you want to use it. I have used in the past the Telerik RAD Editor in a large environment (>10.000 Users)

http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/web-parts/Pages/Content-Editor-Web-Part-using-RadEditor.aspx

This is the most popular SharePoint HTML Editor on the market. But the users where also not happy with it.

The best editors are [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), but there is no supported Sharepoint 2013 integration for these ones or you have do develop the integration by yourself or through a consulting company.

Comment: TinyMCE is good, I've used that before.

Comment: Just test out TinyMCE and the table format tool is good! However how can I integrate it to SharePoint?

Comment: Please look at https://joshmccarty.com/2011/06/use-tinymce-as-the-rich-text-editor-in-sharepoint-forms/#comment-1013 and http://www.andypemberton.com/captech/integrating-tinymce-with-sharepoint-moss-2007/. Its too much to write it here. There is no (!) SharePoint 2013 guide for that as told in my answer. Therefore you need to try out.

Comment: For us RadEditor works just fine, especially the fact that it comes with SP2013 integration (including file management dialogs).

Comment: Telerik is something i have used in past. It slight better then SharePoint OOTB html editor.